# Moving two div elements at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not sure if I'm being too clear with the title. Sorry, it's late and I don't think I have a cleared mind.

Anyway what I want this to do is..

1. When the div(manager) is clicked, the div(managerp) appears.
2. The div(manager) moves to the area the same time managerp moves there. Almost as though they move as one div element.
3. On the next click managerp Fades out, and manager moves back to its original position.

I'm able to do all of that, but it won't return to it's original position. I am a novice when it comes to jQuery, so this is where I ask for your help.

EDIT: The div manager doesn't seem to return to the old position. I've tried editing the css through jQuery to get it to, but it doesn't seem to work.

HTML :

```
    <div id="manager">
        <span>&raquo;</span>
</div>
<div id="managerp" style="">

</div>
```

No, I can't put managerp within manager, it doesn't seem to position itself as good as it should.

jQuery :

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#manager").click(function() {
                $("#manager").css({'margin-left' : '270px', 'border-left' : '0'});
                $("#managerp").toggle("slow", function() {
                    if ($("#managerp").is(':visible'))
                        $("span").html("&laquo;");
                    else 
                        $("span").html("&raquo;");
                });
            });
        });
```

This should help you get the picture of what it's supposed to look like. (Sorry if I am giving way too much information)

[image: One]
[image: Two]

Thank you for your help. If you need me to be more specific as to what it should be doing, just ask.

[image: This is how it looks when it doesn't return correctly.]

Comment: _"but it won't return to it's original position"_ which element is "it?"

Comment: What's the problem? You have the code already.

Comment: The div element manager, I've tried using .css(), but it doesn't budge.

Comment: Wrap both of those elements in another div, and animate/use positioning on that div, don't do it on these two separate divs.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#manager").click(function() {
            $("#managerp").toggle("slow", function() {
                if($("#managerp").is(':visible')){
                    $("span").html("&laquo;");
                    $("#manager").css({'margin-left' : '0px', 'border-left' : '0'});
                }else{
                    $("span").html("&raquo;");
                    $("#manager").css({'margin-left' : '270px', 'border-left' : '0'});
                }
            });
        });
});
```

You have to reset the margin to `0px`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var flag = false; 
     $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#manager").click(function() {
                    if(!flag)
                    {
                        $("#manager").css({'margin-left' : '270px', 'border-left' : '0'});
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#manager").css({'margin-left' : '0px', 'border-left' : '0'});
flag = false;
                    }
                        $("#managerp").toggle("slow", function() {
                            if ($("#managerp").is(':visible'))
                                $("span").html("&laquo;");
                            else 
                                $("span").html("&raquo;");
                        });                
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO your problem is not to deal with jQuery.

the problem is you can't put the #manager and #managerp together as single element

try CSS absolute/relative position

Comment: This is the right answer. Your little tab button should sit inside a larger div with overflow:visible. Then just scoot it over the right edge. Don't use JS when CSS solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) on your code to manipulate multiple elements. Like this

```
 $("#manager, #managerp").css({
    'marginLeft' : '270px', 
    'borderLeft' : '0'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first guess, there's no place in your code which actually resets the margin back. You're just resetting the text, but no margin back to zero. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Actually, you are setting the margin style at the element level, and toggling the style. Which won't work since the element level style is more important.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps ...

You need to reset Margin-Left to 0. Also hide the div ManagerP at the start.

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#managerp").hide();
    $("#manager").click(function() {
    $("#managerp").toggle("slow", function() {
          if ($("#managerp").is(':visible')){
              $("span").html("&laquo;");
              $("#manager").css({'margin-left' : '270px', 'border-left' : '01'});           }
          else {
                $("span").html("&raquo;");
                $("#manager").css({'margin-left' : '0px', 'border-left' : '01'});}
                                            });
        });
    });


</script>       
<body>
<div id="manager">
   <span>&raquo;</span>
</div>
<div id="managerp" style="">
  This is a test for sliding control <br>
  This is Manager P DIV
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apologies for bad formatting... working with notepad isn't fun